# Disallow user to resize form under certain dimensions

Tags: c#, winforms

My form size is 620 by 320 and I'd like the user to resize the form over those dimensions but not under, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Forms have a `MinimumSize` property. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
myform.MinimumSize = new Size(620, 320);
```

Comment: Never, *never* hard-code sizes.  DPI awareness is very important today.